# How to use Native Android ImageView in a Xamarin Forms PCL?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin, but learning quickly. I have what is hopefully a straightforward question. I know that I can customize Xamarin Forms controls per platform using custom renderers, and I also know that I can use native controls that have 0-param constructors with dependency service.

my question is, how do I use a native control (specifically Android ImageView... and eventually obviously WinPhone and iOS counterparts) in my Xamarin Forms PCL app?

A very simple example would go a long way, since I'm just having trouble getting my head around how I would define an interface which would set parameters like buffering, image source, etc. on the platform-specific controls.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any particular reason that you want to explicitly create and use the native ImageView?  Xamarin.Forms built in Image view will use the native control on each platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the latest update to Xamarin Forms this is a newly added feature. 
You can read more about it in the blog - [Embedding Native Controls into Xamarin.Forms](https://blog.xamarin.com/embedding-native-controls-into-xamarin-forms/).

Also you can find samples at [Native Embedding - Adding Platform-Specific Controls to a Xamarin.Forms Layout](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/add-platform-controls/)

On Android, the following code example demonstrates how to add a TextView to a StackLayout and a ContentView:

```
var textView = new TextView (Forms.Context) { Text = originalText, TextSize = 14 };
stackLayout.Children.Add (textView);
contentView.Content = textView.ToView();
```

*For this to work you have to use a Shared Project template and not PCL. For PCL you will have to use Custom Renders.*

Comment: I am pretty sure that the above code only works in Shared projects and not in PCL projects.

Comment: Yes, you are right @hvaughan3. For PCL you need to use custom renders.

Comment: Here's the new/fixed link to the 'Embedding Native Controls into Xamarin Forms' blog post: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/embedding-native-controls-xamarin-forms/